# Why is openshift oc new-app not using the --source-secret I provided?

Tags: github, openshift, openshift-origin

I am starting OS like this:

```
oc cluster up --public-hostname=julio-oc.10.238.41.233.nip.io
```

I also have a private github repo, configured with a deployment key, with only a trivial `Dockerfile`.

I then add the secret as follows:

```
oc secrets new-sshauth sleep-key-rsa --ssh-privatekey=/home/julio/.ssh/sleep-key_rsa
```

If I attempt to create the app, it fails:

```
> oc new-app --source-secret=sleep-key-rsa git@github-isl-01.ca.com:garju09/docker-sleep.git
error: Errors occurred while determining argument types:

git@github-isl-01.ca.com:garju09/docker-sleep.git as a Git repository URL:  Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But if I add the key to the ssh agent, it now works:

```
> ssh-add ~/.ssh/sleep-key_rsa
Identity added: /home/julio/.ssh/sleep-key_rsa (/home/julio/.ssh/sleep-key_rsa)

> oc new-app --source-secret=sleep-key-rsa git@github-isl-01.ca.com:garju09/docker-sleep.git
--> Found Docker image 3fa8225 (2 weeks old) from Docker Hub for "centos:centos7"

    * An image stream will be created as "centos:centos7" that will track the source image
    * A Docker build using source code from git@github-isl-01.ca.com:garju09/docker-sleep.git will be created
      * The resulting image will be pushed to image stream "docker-sleep:latest"
      * Every time "centos:centos7" changes a new build will be triggered
      * WARNING: this source repository may require credentials.
                 Create a secret with your git credentials and use 'set build-secret' to assign it to the build config.
    * This image will be deployed in deployment config "docker-sleep"
    * The image does not expose any ports - if you want to load balance or send traffic to this component
      you will need to create a service with 'expose dc/docker-sleep --port=[port]' later
    * WARNING: Image "centos:centos7" runs as the 'root' user which may not be permitted by your cluster administrator

--> Creating resources ...
    imagestream "centos" created
    imagestream "docker-sleep" created
    buildconfig "docker-sleep" created
    deploymentconfig "docker-sleep" created
--> Success
    Build scheduled, use 'oc logs -f bc/docker-sleep' to track its progress.
    Run 'oc status' to view your app.
```

Why is `new-app` not using the `--source-secret` I specified?

**UPDATE**:

```
> oc version
oc v3.7.0+7ed6862
kubernetes v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://127.0.0.1:8443
openshift v3.7.0+7ed6862
kubernetes v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62
```

My primary source of information here was the following blog: https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-2a-repository-ssh-keys/

Please note that there is no password on the key and I tried various other permutations, including the following. The only thing that works for project creation is `ssh-add`. Curiously, once the project is created, I can empty the `ssh-agent` and OS builds with no problem:

```
oc secrets new-sshauth sleep-key-rsa --ssh-privatekey=/home/julio/.ssh/sleep-key_rsa
oc secrets link builder sleep-key-rsa
oc new-app --source-secret=sleep-key-rsa https://github-isl-01.ca.com/garju09/docker-sleep.git
```

But the above does not work because https requires authentication in our deployment.

```
oc secrets new-sshauth sleep-key-rsa --ssh-privatekey=/home/julio/.ssh/sleep-key_rsa
oc secrets link builder sleep-key-rsa
oc new-app git@github-isl-01.ca.com:garju09/docker-sleep.git
```

Failed as well.

**UPDATE 2:**
I created a github repo that replicates the problem and shows the script that I am using: https://github.com/julio-garcia-fc/docker-sleep

If you clone it and have oc 3.7 you should be able to run `oc.sh` and you can see it fail.

Comment: That you mention needing ``ssh-add`` is because ``oc new-app`` is pulling down the source code to your local machine to run an algorithm to work out how to build it. If you are trying to do a docker type build, supply the argument ``--strategy docker``. If you are using S2I, supply the options ``--strategy source`` and provide the S2I builder name to use in conjunction with the repo details, ie, ``<s2i-builder-image>~<repository-url>``. That way ``oc new-app`` doesn't need to pull repo down to work out how to build source code.

Comment: Do note there is currently (3.6/3.7) a bug in ``oc new-app`` where if using ``--strategy source`` and use ``--image-stream`` for S2I builder name, and ``--code`` for repository URL, that it is incorrectly still pulling repo and unnecessarily trying to work out how to build. Avoid the explicit options and use ``<s2i-builder-image>~<repository-url>`` form of command.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton the bug still seems to exist in openshift 3.11 

`oc new-app --image-stream=php:5.5 --strategy=source --code=https://<private-bitbucket-repo>/git/web_cn.git --context-dir=php-webcn --source-secret=vajra-bitbucket`  


is still trying to clone and analyse the repo,  prompting for bitbucket credentials 

while the short hand method  below works as expected 
i.e without prompting credentials 

`oc new-app php:5.5~https://<private-bitbucket-repo>/git//web_cn.git --context-dir=php-webcn --source-secret=vajra-bitbucket`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to say the builder service account can access your secret. See:

- https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-2b-repository-ssh-keys/

and all the other blog posts in that series.

The command you need is:

```
oc secrets link builder sleep-key-rsa
```

Comment: Thanks Graham. I have seen that blog and that is what I followed. The command you indicate seems to be superfluous when you specify the --source-secret. It does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you not use ``--source-secret`` and try the method as outlined in the blog post? Even try the web console method rather than command line. I know with certainty the methods in the blog post work, so if both command line and web console methods in blog post don't work, then know there is an issue. Also did you ensure that there was no pass phrase on the SSH key?

Comment: Part of the reason I suggest this is that from memory I think ``--source-secret`` is for a different purpose. That is, allowing secrets inside of the build container for the build steps to use. Not for pulling down the Git repository to start with. Pretty sure that ``--source-secret`` existed when wrote the blog posts, but it wasn't what was required, thus why not used. Or maybe ``--source-secret`` didn't exist at time, can't remember.

Comment: So use ``oc secrets new-sshauth``, then ``oc secrets link builder``, and then ``oc set build-secret``.

Comment: Yep, ``--source-secret`` didn't exist in OpenShift Origin 1.5 (OCP 3.5), thus why wasn't used. Anyway, try the prior way. Was confusing it with ``--build-secret``.

Comment: Graham, forgive my ignorance. I am very new at this, but it appears to me that I am caught in chicken-and-egg situation. From what I can tell, I need to run new-app to get a build config, and a build-config is where the build-secret applies. Unfortunately, new-app is what is failing, so I do not see how to invoke build-secret if new-app fails.

Comment: If you use ``oc annotate`` to add the annotation to the secret about what Git repository the secret applies to, you can use ``oc new-app`` and it will use that secret automatically. The blog post explains that way. Since you already had created the build and it was failing, I figured you could just use ``oc set build-secret`` on it. You could even compare the build configuration before and after to see whether it made a change and thus whether ``--source-secret`` did in fact do the same thing.

Comment: Graham, I set up https://github.com/julio-garcia-fc/docker-sleep. If you clone it and run oc.sh with oc 3.7, you may see the problem (or identify what I am doing wrong). You will see that i am annotating the secret, but it still fails. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Can't check it right now myself, but the value of the annotation has to be ``ssh://github.com:julio-garcia-fc/docker-sleep.git``. It needs the ``ssh://`` form and will not accept ``git@github.com:julio-garcia-fc/docker-sleep.git``.

Comment: Should clarify, you can't have the ``git@`` in the value of the annotation. It will not accept that, even when ``ssh://`` form used.

Comment: No luck. I have update the git repo with the code that I am using. I suspect a defect of some sort. I think I will abandon this approach and just experiment with templates. I appreciate your help Graham.

Comment: FWIW, I tried the steps using newer ``--source-secret`` option, with ``oc cluster up`` and it works fine for me on my own private repo with my own keys I created, so not sure what is going on.

Comment: It worked. I had to prefix the URI with "centos~". Thank you Graham.